# vote to repopen

Tags: support

my question was closed because i mentioned societies tendencies toward bigotry toward me. i'm like nearly a universal minority so i bring out the worst in the parts of the majority who hold certain concepts dear. i guess others have difficulty understanding that bigotry exists today. i removed that part

would a mod reopen it please?

https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/19311/are-companies-acting-like-nazis

Comment: Could you please explain why do you think your question fits the [site's guidelines](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I believe your question was closed because it wasn't about history.  Mod's don't re-open questions, the community does.

Comment: @YannisRizos i think the history of papers please is relevant i don't know it

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace ok i thought mods could force open and close but maybe things have changed

Answer (score 4):

History.se closes and reopens questions based on our topical limitations: https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

The linked question is off-topic.  It should not be reopened.